# How to make my windows desktop c# application re-connect to the server in case if the connection lost

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr, signalr.client

I am developing a notification system that contains server side intranet application that using signalR to send notifications into a client side which is in my case a windows desktop c# application .

both applications by the way are c# applications implemented using SignalR and .Net framework 4.5.2.

Currently i make my application connect to the server to recieve notification , i implemented that in the start of windows desktop App.

my issue that i want my application (Windows desktop application) to try to connect to the server in case if the connection lost for any reason while the desktop app is already running.

what is the best way to implement that

here down my c# code that connect my app into the intranet application

```
public static HubConnection connection;
static void Main()
{
    IHubProxy _hub;
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


    string urlToConnectIntoIntranetServer = @"http://localhost:46412";
    connection = new HubConnection(url);
    connection.Headers.Add("Securitytoken", "87654321");
    _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub");
    _hub.On("broadcastMessage", x => reateToastNotification.CreateToast(x));

    connection.Closed += connection_Closed;
    connection.Start().Wait();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
    CreateToastNotification.CreateToast("Hellow world");
}

  static void connection_Closed()
        {
            Pooling(10);
        }
  private static void Pooling(int i)
        {
            int nTimes = i;
            if (nTimes == 0)
                return;

            try
            {
                if (connection!=null)
                 connection.Start().Wait(); 

            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Pooling(nTimes - 1);
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Catch the event where the connection is closed. When it is closed and you want to reconnect, do so in the handler. When it is closed because you're e.g. quitting the application let it close.

Comment: On a side note, you're having some problems formatting your code and it would be nice to fix those to make it more readable

Comment: thanks Ben , i would like to know what are your suggestions to make the code more readable

Comment: so what you mean is to handle the event Closed as what  exists in my code snippet  ? .

Comment: you do `connection.Closed += connection_Closed;` already. Can we see the definition of `connection_Closed`? That would be a good place for the custom handling, yes?

Comment: i did edit the poat to contain my implementation for connection_Closed

Comment: but i am not sure is that the best way to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (It's only an idea and maybe a little ugly^^):

```
        private void Connection_StateChanged(StateChange obj)
        {
            //when the connection is Disconnected
            if (obj.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                var current = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                // start a timer after 30 secs and retry every 15secs
                SetTimer(current.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), StartCon);
            } else {
                if(_timer!=null)
                   _timer.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private async Task StartCon()
        {
            await Connection.Start();
        }

        private Timer _timer ;
        private void SetTimer(TimeSpan starTime, TimeSpan every, Func<Task> action)
        {
            var current = DateTime.Now;
            var timeToGo = starTime - current.TimeOfDay;
            if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                return;
            }
            _timer = new Timer(x =>
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }, null, timeToGo, every);
        }
```